# Has methods secure Config Server by oauth2 token?

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud, microservices, oauth-2.0

## Has methods  secure Config Server by oauth2 token ?

I plan to implement  spring cloud config-server by oauth2 token,so client-server can fetch property by :

```
 cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://user:password@localhost:8888
```

Is it feasible ?

but ... i met some problems .
I start a demo  https://github.com/keryhu/spring-oauth2-config-server.git

It contains  four services :

**1 : eureka** : start first,and can implement service register and discovery,it has no oauth2 enviroment.

**2 : auth-server** : JWT OAuth2 server configuration ,start secondly.

```
    @SessionAttributes("authorizationRequest")
    @EnableResourceServer
    @EnableDiscoveryClient
```

and inmemory user :

```
  security:
    user:
      password: password
```

**3: config-server** : start thirdly

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableConfigServer
@EnableResourceServer
```

and in application.yml :

```
spring:  
  cloud:
     config:
       server:
         git:
           uri: https://github.com/keryhu/cloud-config


security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      jwt:
        keyValue: |
          -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
          ....
          -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

**4: pc-gateway** :  is a client-server,also  a ui server. start lastly

When i test the secured uri: http://localhost:8080/hello, the page was redirected to

`http://localhost:9999/uua/login`

After  entering "**user:password**",it redirects back

```
http://localhost:8080/hello
```

So i think the oauth-server and oauth-client is fine.

but.. i also set the following configuration in bootstrap.yml

```
cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://user:password@localhost:8888
```

When starting pc-gateway service, Fetching config from server has 401 Unauthorized errors :

```
INFO 954 --- [main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888
WARN 954 --- [main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: 401 Unauthorized
```

Need help ! thanks !